# iOS, Open one push notification and the others are gone too

Tags: ios, push-notification

The problem is, when the app is closed and it receives multiple remote/push notifications, if the user opens only one of them then the others get cleared too.

Is there a way to clear the opened one only??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not way to remove only the on push notification. You can't even see how many push notification there are for your app. You will just receive the one notification that the user used to start your app.

Comment: what do you mean with "You can't even see how many push notification there are for your app".. do you mean from code/ programmatically??

Comment: Yes, by code. You can't access the pusch notifications by code, you will only receive the push notification user used the open your app